# Does this code use Bcrypt or just plain blowfish?

Tags: php, hash, passwords, blowfish, bcrypt

I'm learning php security online (using php 5.4) and came across the following code that I'd like to learn about/use. Does the following code use bcrypt and is it a good implementation of blowfish?
If problems exist, can you please suggest a fix or resource. Thanks.

```
    class PassHash {  

    // blowfish  
    private static $algo = '$2a';  

    // cost parameter  
    private static $cost = '$10';  

    // mainly for internal use  
    public static function unique_salt() {  
        return substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,22);  
    }  

    // this will be used to generate a hash  
    public static function hash($password) {  

        return crypt($password,  
                    self::$algo .  
                    self::$cost .  
                    '$' . self::unique_salt());  

    }  

    // this will be used to compare a password against a hash  
    public static function check_password($hash, $password) {  

        $full_salt = substr($hash, 0, 29);  

        $new_hash = crypt($password, $full_salt);  

        return ($hash == $new_hash);  

    }  

}
```

Here is the usage during user registration:

```
// include the class 
require ("PassHash.php");
// ...
// read all form input from $_POST
// ...
// do your regular form validation stuff
// ...
// hash the password
$pass_hash = PassHash::hash($_POST['password']);
// store all user info in the DB, excluding $_POST['password']
// store $pass_hash instead
// ...
```

And here is the usage during a user login process:

```
// include the class  
require ("PassHash.php");        
// read all form input from $_POST
// ...
// fetch the user record based on $_POST['username']  or similar  
// ...
// ... 
// check the password the user tried to login with  
if (PassHash::check_password($user['pass_hash'], $_POST['password']) {  
    // grant access  
    // ...  
} else {  
    // deny access  
    // ...  
}
```

Comment: Also: do I need to store the salt in mysql or do I just leave it as an internal function of the passhash class?

Comment: You don't need to store the salt, it's already in the returned value of PassHash::hash. And yes, this is a technique similar to bcrypt. About as good as you can get with only core PHP.

Comment: So the unique salt is included in the hash? isn't this like handing over a key to a hacker or is the salt part also encrypted...shouldn't the salt and the hash be kept separate?

Comment: Also I hate to be pedantic but is it similar or the same? And should I increase the number of rounds somehow (code example needed if this is the case).

Comment: I don't know if they're the same or not, you'll have to look at the crypt() source for that. They're just both Blowfish-based. Also, the salt is nothing like a key, it just protects you from rainbow table-based attacks.

Comment: Thanks, I can see from the substr code that the unique salt length will be 22 characters and I don't need to store that, but I DO need to store the hash..does anyone know what type of field (number of characters, type, etc) I should prepare for storing the hash returned by this?

Comment: `character varying` or `text` will do.

Answer (score 0):

> Short answer :

Yes it does use bcrypt blowfish (in PHP blowfish is the current algorithm for bcrypt)

> Correct answer :

Why not use a trusted PHP compatibility library like [this one?](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

The benefits of using this over the one you posted? :

1. It is widely used by many people (must be trusted and well taken by the community)
2. Allow for forward compatibility with php 5.5 native bcrypt function (hence name for passwd_compat) more info here : [Info Here!](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash)
3. Allows for a rehash which is genius (pretty much if you decide to crank up the cost of the algorithm you can easily do so and check if the cost matches the one in the library file if not then you can just update the password)

Bottom line : You can only go wrong with bcrypt if you don't know what your doing. One thing to remember is : do not reinvent the wheel if there are already wheels out there.

Hopefully this answer can help you out / expand your knowledge.